# Can a website tell the difference between an organic mousemove and a move performed using PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onmousemove

PhantomJS has a neat feature allowing one to move a mouse by sending a `mousemove` event not to the website in question but to what I assume is WebKit.

Is there any way for a browser to tell that the actions on their site are "synthetic"? If I was in charge of defending against that, I reckon I'd first off look for mouse cursors that teleport impossibly or button that get pressed while the cursor is nowhere near them (though jQuery can be at fault here).

Could I create a minefield of `div`s around the submit button with listening for `mouseover`, and if the form is submitted without any of them triggered, call foul play or something?

**Is there any difference to a website where the `onmousemove` event originates from? Can it tell using JavaScript?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a minefield of `div`s, if you feel like doing it. And no, there is no way to determine where a `onMouseMove` event originates from. You cannot tell using JavaScript.

From the [PhantomJS documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html):

> The events are **not** synthetic DOM events, each event is sent to the web page as if it comes as part of user interaction.